# 16digit Hex Time stamp (convert using python)

Tags: python, encoding, timestamp

The line below is from an xml file:

#40E5095E48B9141A

Does anyone recognize this timestamp format and know for to convert using python 3 code?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(0x40E5095E)
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(0x48B9141A)
```

I think it's a range of timestamps.Your `#40E5095E48B9141A` has two parts in it.

```
1.40E5095E 2.48B9141A
```

Converting them to timestamps:

```
datetime.datetime(2004, 7, 2, 12, 36, 6)
datetime.datetime(2008, 8, 30, 15, 4, 18)
```